# CustomAdapter that extend BaseAdapter with different Item Type Based JSON

Tags: android, json, listview, custom-adapter

[image: listview with different type of row]

Hi there. I have a `JSON` that parsed in a `ListView`.
My JSON Objects are like this:

```
Object[
  {
    category{},
    create_time: "2014-04-18T22:47:04",
    file_url: "FILE URL",
    id: 1,
    Type: video,
    video_dow_cnt: 120
  },
  {
    category{},
    create_time: "2014-04-18T22:47:04",
    file_url: "FILE URL",
    id: 1,
    Type: Sound,
    sound_like: 11
  },
  {
    category{},
    create_time: "2014-04-18T22:47:04",
    file_url: "FILE URL",
    id: 1,
    Type: Image,
    Image_Type: jpg
  },
  {
    category{},
    create_time: "2014-04-18T22:47:04",
    file_url: "FILE URL",
    id: 1,
    Type: Text,
    description: DESCRIPTION,
    text_like: 25
  },
]
```

As you can see, i have more than one type object. for each type, I created a xml file like this:

```
Sound_Row.xml -> for Sound
video_Row.xml -> foe Video
photo_Row.xml -. for Images
text_Row.xml -> for Text
```

I know how to create custom adapter by extending the base adapter, But my issue is how to using of "Type" field in `getViewItemType()` to determine which of the layouts to use for the ListView.

Comment: feel free to show your code.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layout-for-each-row

Comment: As i said i have a listview with more than two item type...is there a clear tutorial or example?!